# Compare rows in different table having same columns

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I have 2 tables tbl_A and tbl_A_temp. Both the table have the same schema. their primary key differ since they are identity columns. Is there a way i can compare the two rows in these two table and get to know if they differ.I will be inserting data from tbl_A_temp to tbl_A, i need this compare just to make sure that I am not inserting any duplicate data in the main tables.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you.  Basically, since you don't have a primary key to join on, you'll need to perform a `LEFT JOIN` on all your other fields.  If any are different, then the `NULL` check will be true:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_A_temp t
   LEFT JOIN tbl_A a ON 
      t.field1=a.field1 AND t.field2=a.field2 AND ...
WHERE a.field1 IS NULL
```

I've also seen others use `CHECKSUM`, but have run into issues myself with it returning false positives.

Comment: Thanks.. this approach eases the solution a bit.